# The renders on my pc and mac differs

Tags: rendering, animation, osx

I have an interesting problem, I work with blender on my Macbook pro M2 pro
and have created a animation, for the rendering I am using 3 pc to help with cutting down the rendering time.
Problem is the pc and mac renders differently...
I'm afraid I cannot share the file since it is a working project and protected etc

but this is a render from a pc
[image: PC render]

and this is the result on my mac using GPU and metal

[image: Mac]

Comment: and this is what I get on my mac (running gpu with metal)

Comment: You may want to highlight the difference with annotations.  I don't see any...

Comment: There is a big black vertical stripe right across the middle of the image >.< @Pacho check your geometry, looks like you have overlapping faces or their normals are not pointing outside.

Comment: @james_t You don't see _any_ differences? There is no black stripe visible in the bottom picture which is not in the top picture? Apart from the area in the top right being darker. Pacho: is it exactly the same file? To me it looks as if there is something visible in the bottom image that is hidden in the top one...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann -- i prefer the person posing the question not have me hunt around.   Eyes Wide Crossed here.

Comment: @james_t He found the answer to his problem and posted it 10 hours ago...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, I found today that one of the pcs were also producing the same result as the mac, so I started checking differences, they all use the same files, but...apparantly it is in which type of GPU renderer I choose, so I switched to CUDA on my pcs and they produced the same image as the mac.

Answer (score -2):

Something that immediately stands out to me is the harshness of the brightest parts of the image. I believe if you check the *Color Management* settings in the *Render panel* and set the view transform to *Filmic,* the output should look like the bottom one.

[image: Location of the Color Management settings]

Comment: If you place the images on top of each other, you'll see no difference in the images except for the broken geometry with the black stripe. Also OP says he is cutting the same scene down to different PCs, so one can assume the Blender setup is identical.

Comment: I partly agree with @taiyo - although there are differences between the images and the brightness in certain areas is different, the _Color Management_ is definitely not the reason for this harsh black stripe.